# Google Sheets duration between 2 timestamps where the ending timestamp crosses into midnight

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I'm calculating the durations of time between two timestamps.

As an example, I have column `A`, which is the starting time, and column `B`, which is the stopping time. Both `A` and `B` are formatted as `Time`. Column `C` holds the ***duration*** between `A` and `B`, and is formatted as `Duration`.

The formula `=SUM(B1 - A1)` works fine for the most part, until I reach a situation in which `B1` has crossed into midnight of the next day

For example if I have the following:

```
  A   |     B     |     C
------------------------------
23:30 |   23:40   |   0:10:00
23:30 |   23:50   |   0:20:00
23:30 |   00:00   | -23:30:00
23:30 |   00:10   | -23:20:00
```

How do I circumvent this issue and have `C3` & `C4` properly calculate the value to be `0:30:00` and `0:40:00` respectively? My timestamps don't include date-related information, columns `A` and `B` *only* hold `HH:MM:SS` times. These durations will also **never** be longer than a maximum of 3 hours, so there's no need to worry about it correctly detecting overflow situations like `Day 1 12:00:00 -> Day 2: 12:00:00 = 24:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For mixed duration that crossed midnight of the next day** *(overlaps midnight)*
try either of the following formulas.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A42:A="",,MOD(B42:B-A42:A, 1)))
```

[image]

**OR**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A42:A)<>0, 
               IF(B42:B55<A42:A,B42:B-A42:A+1,B42:B-A42:A),""))
```

[image]

*Please adjust ranges to your needs*

Answer (score 0):

If you format the result column as `Time`, you don't need to change anything. If not, here is another option:

```
=B2-A2+(B2<A2)
```

[image]

**Edit**

An attempt with an array formulas:

[image]

First two results formatted as `Time`, last as `Duration`

Comment: *"If you format the result column as Time, you don't need to change anything. If not, here is another option"*. Your formulas will work when using using single cells.  I think though issues will appear if used within an arrayformula. Especially when empty cells are present. Have you tried them?

Comment: @marikamitsos Tried, no change, see the edit. Empty cells are considered to be midnight.

Comment: *"Empty cells are considered to be midnight"*. I know. And the whole column is filled with `00:00:00`. Shouldn't they be returned as blanks?